# removing specific thousand separator in specific column in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have set of numbers format like 1.8789 and would like the output to become 1878.9

These number is inside specific column and have million lines to be update.

I didn't find any similar to solve this.
Below is the highlight screenshot.

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiJHI.jpg)

Comment: You mean you want to multiply the value in the last row by 1000?

Comment: Please, don't post image, give us your example file as text. Do you want to modify only the last column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to change only the last column. Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.(\d{3})(?=\d*$)`
- Replace with: `$1.`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.              # a dot
(\d{3})         # group 1, 3 digits
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \d*             # 0 or more digits
    $               # end of line
)               # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, 3 digits
.           # a dot
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the exact style/precision of number you gave, you may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    (\d+)\.(\d{3})(\d+)
Replace: $1$2.$3
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ...

Find: `(?<=1)\.(\d{3})`
Replace with: `$1.`

Comment: You are welcome,  Glad it helped you...